# Redirect AJAX request to another page/View using server Transfer ASP.Net MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way that a MVC Action, initiated  by an  AJAX request,  can redirect the response  directly to another page/View without sending a JavaScript “*window.location=…”* to the client first? In other words, directly transferring the response on the server side and avoiding the roundtrip to the client.

This is a more general question about the possibility to transfer directly an AJAX call, but here is a more specific scenario:

1. The browser sends an AJAX request to the server and based on the request data the controller's logic performs some operations.
2. For the majority of the cases, the controller needs to return back a result (JSON) to the same page. However, for few cases it needs to redirect to another page and it returns back a script to redirect the page, but this causes another roundtrip to the browser. The  flow is:   Page  – Server – Page – Server – New Page, and the question is if this can be optimized to Page – Server – New Page .

Comment: Can you be more specific about the behaviour you're after? Are you trying to have something done with AJAX but still redirect the user somewhere? Are you trying to have an AJAX request redirected? Do you want a redirect to occur after an AJAX call?

Comment: No, it's impossible. Any type of HTTP response will be obtained by ajax and it's your concern to handle this at client. The only option is to make another request.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really possible, no.

The browser has two options to choose between:

- Go to a page
- Make an AJAX call to a page

It can't make an AJAX call and automatically redirect based on what the server decides because the client (browser) doesn't know what the server has decided on before the response is even received by the browser.

The traditional approach (which you're avoiding) is:

- The browser makes an asynchronous request to the server
- The server responds with data informing the client to redirect
- The client makes a new request to the server via `window.location`
- The server responds with the new page

However you want to skip a step by doing:

- The browser makes an asynchronous request to the server
- The client makes a new request to the server via `window.location`
- The server responds with the new page

But the client doesn't know that it needs to redirect and/or it doesn't know how to.

### One (ugly) possibility

One idea that comes to mind to pseudo-achieve what you want is to have MVC render the required view and send the whole thing back to the client via JSON rather than a redirection approach. Let me explain.

- The browser makes an asynchronous request to the server
- The server determines which page needs to be displayed and renders the view ([Generating a view without a controller in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483114/generating-a-view-without-a-controller-in-mvc/19483438#19483438))
- The server serialises the resulting HTML as JSON
- The client receives the JSON, and re-renders the entire page with the new markup (i.e. completely replace)

You can also alter the URL and history of the browser to make it "feel" like a redirect by [manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

However I would like to point out that this "solution" is more of an amusing/interesting approach. This isn't really a good way to go about the problem.